# TreeMap sorting not working when using Collectors.groupingBy()

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, treemap

My list is like,

```
List<Map<String, Object>> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

where my list is as,

[{column_changed=first_name, sequence_number=190001, change_date=2019-01-01, customer_number=3100},
{column_changed=last_name, sequence_number=190001, change_date=2019-01-01, customer_number=3100},
{column_changed=mail_id, sequence_number=19002, change_date=2019-01-05, customer_number=3101},
{column_changed=date_of_birth, sequence_number=190002, change_date=2019-01-05, customer_number=3101},
{column_changed=nationality, sequence_number=190002, change_date=2019-01-05, customer_number=3101},
{column_changed=contact_number, sequence_number=19003, change_date=2019-01-10, customer_number=3102}]

I initialize an instance of Map as follows,

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

When I use Collectors.groupingBy() using sequence_number,

```
mySortedMap = sortedList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(change -> (String)change.get("sequence_number")));
```

the output is as follows,

{190001=[{column_changed=first_name, sequence_number=190001, change_date=2019-01-01, customer_number=3100},
{column_changed=last_name, sequence_number=190001, change_date=2019-01-01, customer_number=3100}],
19003=[{column_changed=contact_number, sequence_number=19003, change_date=2019-01-10, customer_number=3102}], 
19002=[{column_changed=mail_id, sequence_number=19002, change_date=2019-01-05, customer_number=3101},
{column_changed=date_of_birth, sequence_number=190002, change_date=2019-01-05, customer_number=3101},
{column_changed=nationality, sequence_number=190002, change_date=2019-01-05, customer_number=3101}]}

But I need the **keys to be sorted**. Though the instance is a TreeMap, the keys are not sorted. I could'nt figure out why. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Each time you write `variable = …`, you are overwriting the contents of the variable. So whatever you have assigned to it before, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are changing the object referred by mySortedMap. The **map returned by groupingBy() can be of any type**. From documentation,

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map or List objects returned.

If your list is sorted try using,

```
mySortedMap = sortedList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    change -> (String) change.get("sequence_number"), TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```